# How can I read only top level data in firebase realtime database, and not all the lower level data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So the simple answer here would be to use Firestore database, since it offers functionality to read only top level documents, but it is important for my app to use realtime database, I want to read the top level data, and only read the lower level data when user requests it specifically. I read the Realtime Database documentation and it says[image]

So, it's not allowed 'by default'. I want to know if it is allowed any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Read operations in the Firebase Realtime Database SDKs always return all data under all paths that are returned. There is no method in the SDKs that returns only the keys under a node, and not the further data under it.

I'd recommend changing your data structure to have an "index" data structure with just the keys, while also keeping your current structure. For example:

```js
Users: {
  "userId1": {
    name: "...",
    address: "...",
    createdAt: 1932831239123,
    lastSeenAt: 1932831239127,
  },
  "userId2": {
    name: "...",
    address: "...",
    createdAt: 1632831239123,
    lastSeenAt: 1732831239127,
  }
},
UserKeys: {
  "userId1": true,
  "userId2": true
}
```

*The `true` values in the `UserKeys` nodes are needed because you can't create a path without a value, but have no specific meaning.*

Now you can can load just the keys, or the full profiles as needed.

---

Alternatively you can use the REST API and [pass the `shallow=true` parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#shallow).